# Reapply all css-styles (external stylesheets and inline) after Modernizr is done applying classnames to 'Body'

Tags: css, repaint, modernizr

I want to use the classnames that [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) sets on the body to apply css styles defined in an external stylesheet.

For example on touch devices Modernizr does:

```
<body class="touch other stuff here">
..
</body>
```

Not in an external stylesheet I might have (contrived):

```
.touch .somediv{
  background: green; 
}
```

On pageload this style isn't applied because the css is inspected before Modernizr had the chance to apply the `touch` classname.

So how to tell the browser, in a cross-browser way, to reapply all styles?

Comment: This shouldn't be needed, the classes should be applied. [The modernizr docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/#installing) recommend putting the modernizr script tag in the document head after the style sheet links but note that if you don't need to support IE8, you can include modernizr anywhere.

Comment: yeah I silently hoped that would be the case. Ok, I'm double checking what's up

Comment: ahh. ok I forgot that for testing I'm using a client-side less-compiler. That's almost certainly screwing things up. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Client Side less compiler interfered.. It just works without